# TinyMCE Editor in SugarCRM

Tags: tinymce, sugarcrm

I just want to add some buttons in TinyMCE Editor in SugarCRM. I wrote standard code for add Buttons but all buttons is not show up in "Quick email compose", I have problems with tablecontrols, advhr and preview buttons in Quick email compose for Sugar.

Any idea???

Thanks.

Comment: this doesn't help much. you need to show us what you tried and what you want to achieve, what is your tinymce configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while since @Jordan sent this, but if it can help someone..
SugarCRM made this :
http://support.sugarcrm.com/04_Find_Answers/03_Developers/100Customization/Modifying_the_TinyMCE_Editor